# Cannot implicitly convert type 'system.collections.generic.list<ShapeDrawer.Shape> to <ShapeDrawer.Shape>

Tags: c#, list

I'm new to C#. I'm trying to create a property that creates a new List "result" (Data type is Shape) to then loop through it and if the mouse is clicked it would add the Shape found in the list to the "result"list and then return "result".
However,  I'm getting the following error:

`Cannot implicitly convert type 'system.collections.generic.list<ShapeDrawer.Shape> to <ShapeDrawer.Shape>`

This is my code:

```
    public  Shape SelectedShapes
    {
        get
        {
            List <Shape> result = new List<Shape>();
            foreach (Shape s in _shapes)
            {
                if(s.selected == true)
                {
                    result.Add(s);
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What didn't you unserstand? Your property contract that it returns `Shape` and you are trying to return `List<Shape>`

Comment: Hi Selvin, you are right. That was the error. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `SelectedShapes` property's return type is not matching with what you are really returning from the `get` accessor. You are returning a `List <Shape>` objects from your property get but your property return a `Shape object`. Change your property signature from

```
public Shape SelectedShapes{//your code}
```

to

```
public List<Shape> SelectedShapes{//your code}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change yor property type from Shape to List of Shapes, or return result[index]

Answer (score 0):

As Selvin commented: you are trying to return `List<Shape>` while your return type is

`public Shape SelectedShapes`

either change to:
`public List<Shape> SelectedShapes`

or if you only want to return one that's selected then:

```
public  Shape SelectedShapes
{
    get
    {
        foreach (Shape s in _shapes)
        {
            if(s.selected == true)
            {
                return s;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```